# Java - Android How to return a List from a Class to multiple Classes?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a reusable Class on Android that fetches Users data from a Firebase Database, creates a list of  Users Models, and returns that list to any other classes that might need the list. But I'm not being able to do it. I won't bother you with all the code, but what I got is basically this:

```
Class Reusable {
//declare FireBase Auth, DatabaseReference, etc.
private Context mContext;
private List<Users> mUserList;

 public Reusable (Context context){
       mContext = context;
        mUserList= new ArrayList<>();
  }
}

public void getUsersIdFromDb(){
   List<Strings> idList = = new ArrayList<>();    

 //gets  Users Id from Database and save it to idList:

    idList.addAll(ids); //ids are ids fetched from Database
   Log.d("StepOne",Integer.toString(idList.size(); //returns correct number of ids
    createListOfModels(idList);
}


private void createListOfModels(final List<Strings> list){  

 //compares fetched ids with ids inside logged user node 
 //if it passes:

    for(String id: list){
        String name = datasnapshot.child(id).child("name).getValue();
        String pic= datasnapshot.child(id).child("pic).getValue();
        UserModel user = new UserModel(name, pic);
        mUserList.add(user); 
       }

        processListOfUsers(mUserList);

    }

private void processListOfUsers(List<Users> list){
 for (User u: list){
  mUserList.add(u);
        Set<Users> hs = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        hs.addAll(mUserList);
        mUserList.clear();
        mUserList.addAll(hs);
 Log.d("StepThree",Integer.toString(mUserList.size(); //returns correct number of Users
 }
}

public List<Users> getList(){

    return mUserList;
}
```

Then, when calling the Reusable class:

```
public SomeClass  extends AppCompatActivity {

   //onCreate, etc...

   Reusable reusable = new Reusable(SomeClass.this);
reusable.getUsersIdFromDb();
int i = reusable.getList().size();
Log.d("FromSomeClass", Integer.toString(i);
//returns 0 when it should return the size of the List from Reusable;
//How do I get the List From Reusable Class??
}
```

As you can see from the size of the list at the Log, it is returning an empty list. How should I set Reusable, so that it returns the list when other classes call?

I'm still finding my way through Java and Android, so I'd appreciate your help.

[EDIT] Maybe it has something to do with the fact that Firebase calls are Asynchronous? Because, you see, as long as I'm passing the results to the parameters, the Logs return a full List. But calling a method outside this chain, perhaps triggers its execution outside the Firebase thread, where the list is still empty.

Comment: Hi, Gino. Yes, I've checked. Everything logs correctly from inside the Reusable Class. Problem is when instantiating it.

Comment: What is the purpose of `processListOfUsers`? Is it for removing duplicate users...? It looks like the problem's there. For one, you are removing/clearing items from `list` (=`mUserList`) _while_ you are looping through it. And two, you are passing `mUserList` when you shouldn't need to because it's already a class member (you can access it directly inside `processListOfUsers`).

Comment: No, Gino. The Log (StepThree) also returns the size of the List. And I can't access from processListOfUsers because it requires a list parameter. It receives the list of Users with duplicates and removes it. If I pass an empty list from another class, it will also return empty.

Comment: Unrelated to the immediate problem, but if you are expecting the same list to be available in different activities you'll need to make a Singleton or some static variables.

Comment: You are right, Tyler. Thank you all.

Comment: Oh OK. Sorry, I got confused by the brackets, I thought the method was part of the same class. Yeah, you'll have to make `mUserList` available to that method instead of passing it around.

Comment: Can you fix the braces so it's clear which methods are in loops and which aren't? As Gino noted, `processListOfUsers` as written appears to be iterating `mUserList`, adding its entries to itself, and clearing itself inside the for-each loop. Turning this into a working example that demonstrates the problem would also be helpful

Comment: you just created an instance of idList and then you are adding id's to it inside getUsersIdFromDb() method. Where are the id's?

Comment: @TylerV done. AIK, ids are the ids fecthed from Database. Edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: The code you have posted is still filled with syntax errors. If I correct them, the list is still being cleared inside the loop of itself which is invalid (and results in a ConcurrentModificationException). For example, remove the context, put dummy items in the list to mimic the database lookup, and make an example someone else could run that reproduces the issue. If I remove the questionable code in `processListOfUsers` it works as expected and doesn't show the issue you've described.

Comment: This is my best guess at what you're trying to do, and it works. https://pastebin.com/UHRYLsKy

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite get what the problem is you're trying to solve. If it is the fact that it returns zero then that's because you never fill the list with anything in this code. The list exists, it's just empty.

The Constructor creates an empty list (size 0)

```
public Reusable (Context context){
   mContext = context;
    mUserList= new ArrayList<>(); 
}
```

Then you actually DO get the list.

First you create a new reusable which creates an empty list inside it

```
Reusable reusable = new Reusable(SomeClass.this);
```

Then you get the size of that list which is zero 
 
`int i = reusable.getList().size();`

There isn't an error here, you just need to fill the list in the constructor or somewhere.

Comment: The list is filled inside Reusable, through the getUsersIdFromDb() method, that calls the other methods from within itself. But it doesn't update mList. I've Edited my question to include the call to getUsersIdFromDb(), which I forgot. The result is the same: No list.